# Имитация нажатия в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Как имитировать через код нажатие мыши/пальца и указать координаты.

Comment: `Google: unity3d fake input`

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]

public class ButtonFakeClick : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Click () {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: А что написать вместо Button для кнопки мыши?

Comment: Ты указал тег `unity3d-ui` по приколу или по тупости? А `unity3d-editor` для чего? На что нажим должен быть?

Comment: @Yaroslav сюдя по тегам, на сонную артерию